# In Redis Databases how do we need to calculate the table size

Tags: database, performance, memory, redis, nosql

How do we need to calculate the table size in Redis databases

I am able to calculate the size of the db using dbsize command it displays how many count of keys are available in the table but I need to calculate the size of the table.

Do anyone help me on this above query

Comment: Redis doesn't have tables. Please use the correct terminology in your question.